# GoogleTest Getting False Coverage

Tags: c++, googletest

So I am doing unit testing for a company that I work for. I am working on a running application that I need to terminate from an outside source which works fine. Well the problem is that I know for a fact that the function that I am testing is getting called. The statements inside the functions are also being executed and I put 28 cout statements throughout the whole function and all of them were printed out on the console. When I finally terminate the app and go to open up the .gcno file to see the coverage and that opened fine too. I look at the % coverage and it says I only have 3.09% coverage. I then knew for a fact that all of my cout statements were printed out so obviously those were hit and should show coverage but the appeared red. As did every other statement and the function called to run to continuous while loop is red, meaning not called. But the while loop INSIDE the "uncalled function" was green and was hit 54 times.

I am quite confused and think this is a Google Test problem and I was just wondering if anyone else who has used Google Test has had this problem before when you know things are being hit and called but GTest says no its not.

Thanks for your help!

Here is the makefile that I am using I assume this is what you wanted to see

```
################################################################################
# Automatically-generated file. Do not edit!
################################################################################

-include ../makefile.init

RM := rm -rf

# All of the sources participating in the build are defined here
-include sources.mk
-include test/subdir.mk
-include src/subdir.mk
-include subdir.mk
-include objects.mk

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
ifneq ($(strip $(C++_DEPS)),)
-include $(C++_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CC_DEPS)),)
-include $(CC_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CPP_DEPS)),)
-include $(CPP_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(CXX_DEPS)),)
-include $(CXX_DEPS)
endif
ifneq ($(strip $(C_UPPER_DEPS)),)
-include $(C_UPPER_DEPS)
endif
endif

-include ../makefile.defs

# Add inputs and outputs from these tool invocations to the build variables 

# All Target
all: TestSomething

# Tool invocations
TestSomething: $(OBJS) $(USER_OBJS)
@echo 'Building target: $@'
@echo 'Invoking: GCC C++ Linker'
g++ -L/proj/COTS/log4cxx/current/lib64 -L/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib64 -L/proj/COTS/ldapc++            /current          /lib64 -L/proj/COTS/qpid/current/lib64 -L/proj/COTS/protobuf/current/lib64 -L/proj    /COTS/boost/current/lib64 -m64 -fprofile-arcs -o "TestSomething" $(OBJS)     $(USER_OBJS) $(LIBS)
@echo 'Finished building target: $@'
@echo ' '

# Other Targets
clean:
-$(RM) $(OBJS)$(C++_DEPS)$(C_DEPS)$(CC_DEPS)$(CPP_DEPS)$(EXECUTABLES)$(CXX_DEPS)$(C_UPPER_DEPS)         TestSomething
-@echo ' '
```

.PHONY: all clean dependents
.SECONDARY:

-include ../makefile.targets

Comment: Problems with coverage of template code maybe?

Comment: For me that sounds like wrong object files to source file match. Do you really rebuilt your code from the source which is presented to gcov? Can you provide a small example with a small makefile which do all steps you are doing? Nobody can give you an answer with the small info you provide I think.